# object foo has two props bar and baz , how to infer baz type by bar's value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type OneType = {a: string};
type TwoType = {b: number};
type DefineItem = {
   bar: 'one' | 'two',
   baz: OneType | TwoType
};

const items: DefineItem = {
  bar: 'one',
  baz: ???
}
```

**expect:**

when bar === 'one', infer baz's type is OneType

when bar === 'two', infer baz's type is TwoType

Answer (score 2):

You could define a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) of two types:

```
type OneType = {a: string};
type TwoType = { b: number };

type DefineItem = {
    bar: 'one',
    baz: OneType
} | {
    bar: 'two',
    baz: TwoType
};

const item1: DefineItem = {
    bar: 'one',
    baz: { a: 'hello' }
}

const item2: DefineItem = {
    bar: 'two',
    baz: { b: 5 }
}
```

See this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20OneType%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20string%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20TwoType%20%3D%20%7B%20b%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20DefineItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20'one'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20OneType%0D%0A%7D%20%7C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20'two'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20TwoType%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20item1%3A%20DefineItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20'one'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20'hello'%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20item2%3A%20DefineItem%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20'two'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20%7B%20b%3A%205%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Documentation about [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) seems relevant here